# Number in parentheses after enum instance

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I am reading a book on programming and I met such thing:

```
public static enum Month {
JANUARY(1),
FEBRUARY(2),
MARCH(3),
APRIL(4),
MAY(5),
JUNE(6),
JULY(7),
AUGUST(8),
SEPTEMBER(9),
OCTOBER(10),
NOVEMBER(11),
DECEMBER(12);
Month(int index) {
this.index = index;
}
```

What does a number in parentheses mean after an enum instance? Is it an enum constructor?

Comment: Yes, `JANUARY(1)` basically means the constructor `Month( int index)` is being called. For more information you could refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), the JavaDoc directly on the classes or any of the numerous tutorials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does a number in parentheses mean after an enum instance? Is it
>   an enum constructor?

`JANUARY(1)`, `FEBRUARY(2)`, etc...  are indeed enum constructors.

But a number is not necessary required to specify a constructor in an enum. Here you have a number but it could be anything else and it could also have as many arguments as required.

Note that actually the enum declaration misses the `index` field and could not compile.
It would be correct :

```
public static enum Month {
    JANUARY(1),
    FEBRUARY(2),
    MARCH(3),
    APRIL(4),
    MAY(5),
    JUNE(6),
    JULY(7),
    AUGUST(8),
    SEPTEMBER(9),
    OCTOBER(10),
    NOVEMBER(11),
    DECEMBER(12);

    private int index;

    Month(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

I would add that an enum is above all a class. So each enum values (here `JANUARY`, `FEBRUARY`, ...) will be instantiated by invoking the class constructor.
And as for any class, as you don't define a constructor the compiler will generate a default with no arg.
So it is valid :

```
public static enum Fruit {
    APPLE(),
    ORANGE();       

    Fruit() {
    }
}
```

That is also valid :

```
public static enum Fruit {
    APPLE(),
    ORANGE();       
}
```

But for enums with no arg in the constructor, we generally use this convenient syntax reserved for enums  :

```
public static enum Fruit {
    APPLE,  // with no parenthesis
    ORANGE; // with no parenthesis  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the constructor being invoked by every enum value:

```
Month(int index) {
this.index = index;
}
```